# Why won't this static variable increment when using generics?

Tags: c#, .net, generics, static, auto-increment

I need a certain class to contain a static member that keeps track of everytime an instance of that class is instantiated, essentially so that each instance of the class has a unique index. It works with a non-generic class but this generic implementation fails whenever the type T differs between instances:

```
class A<T>
{
   private static int counter;

   private static int Counter {
       get { 
          Increment(); 
          return counter; 
       }
   }

   private static void Increment() {
       counter++; 
   }

   public int Index; 

   public A()
   {
       this.Index = Counter; // using A<T>.Counter makes no difference

       Console.WriteLine(this.Index);      
   }
}


class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var a = new A<string>();
        var b = new A<string>(); 
        var c = new A<string>();
        var d = new A<int>(); 
    }
}
```

The output is:

1

2

3

1

As soon as the type T switches to int instead of string, the counter resets.

Does this fail by design, and if so what is the reason or how can I get around it? Or is it a bug? It makes sense to some degree because the type T, being generic, is in the class declaration, but..

Comment: As an aside, you are creating a property whose getter has an observable side effect. Microsoft guidelines recommend using a method rather than a property in that situation.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Each different `T` creates a new class for `A<T>` and hence distinct static counters.

To get around this you can use inheritance like so:

```
abstract class A
{
   protected static int counter;
}

class A<T> : A
{
   private static int Counter {
       get { 
          Increment(); 
          return counter; 
       }
   }

   private static void Increment() {
       counter++; 
   }

   public int Index; 

   public A()
   {
       this.Index = Counter;

       Console.WriteLine(this.Index);      
   }
}
```

Comment: Out of the solutions I think this is the most elegant and least intrusive. Thanks!

Comment: ...Each different `T` of value type, for reference types single generic type wrapper will be created and shared across all final implementations

Comment: If you have `A<MyClass>` and `A<MyClass2>` - they will share static variables, but `A<int>` and `A<double>` does not

Comment: @sll - I just wrote some test code and they all shared the same static variable - even the value types.

Comment: Please see my updated  answer, I've added some code which demonstrates what I mean. Please check it and let me know perhaps we were talking about different things

Comment: @sll That is incorrect, they do *not* share static variables. Try it. They share JITed assembly code, not static variables.`A<MyClass>.Counter` is independent of `A<MyClass2>.Counter`. How else could you possibly have type safety for static fields that are or contain type `T`? The fact that reference type generic parameters share code is an implementation detail that can't leak out as different runtimes are allowed to implement this differently if they wish.

Answer (score 26):

Not a bug - this is by design, and is a consequence of how generics work.

A generic type like your `A<T>` serves as a template - when you use type parameters, the compiler generates an actual class with that type `T`, and a different one will be created for each different type `T`.

This explains the results you see - there is a static field for the `A<int>` and another one for the `A<string>`.

Answer (score 10):

This is because different types are generated under the hood for classes with different generic type parameters. This difference is only for the value type parameters as kindly noted by Ben in comment.

Check out these MSDN articles:

- [Generics in the Run Time](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f4a6ta2h.aspx)
- [Reflection and Generic types](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms172334.aspx)

### EDIT:

Consider following code:

```
public abstract class GenericBase<T>
{
    public static int Counter { get; set; }        
}

public class GenericInt : GenericBase<int>
{        
}

public class GenericLong : GenericBase<long>
{        
}

public class GenericDecimal : GenericBase<decimal>
{        
}

[TestFixture]
public class GenericsTests
{
    [Test]
    public void StaticContextValueTypeTest()
    {
        GenericDecimal.Counter = 10;
        GenericInt.Counter = 1;
        GenericLong.Counter = 100;

       // !! At this point value of the Counter property
       // in all three types will be different - so does not shared across
       // all types
    }
}
```

Comment: "different types are generated" is somewhat misleading.  Static member variables are instanced for each set of generic type parameters.  Methods are only instanced for value types, all reference types share a single implementation.

Comment: Yep exactly, I will add this to answer

Comment: This is an important difference between how they might work in, say, Java. They are both called generics, and both attempt to solve the same problem, but they're not identical. If you're used to working in one, you will be in for a few surprises when you start working in the other!

Answer (score 7):

A generic class is a template from which other classes are created.  A `List<String>` and a `List<int>` are two completely different classes, despite them both originating from `List<T>`.

Have your generic classes reference a non-generic class that holds the counter.  Do not put the static class inside the generic class.  This will cause the static class to be generated for each value of `T`.

```
class A<T>
{
    private static int Counter {
        get {
            ACounter.Increment();
            return ACounter.counter;
        }
    }

    public int Index;

    public A()
    {
       this.Index = Counter;

       Console.WriteLine(this.Index);
    }
}

static class ACounter
{
    static ACounter() {
        counter = 0;
    }

    public static int counter {get; private set;};

    public static void Increment() {
        counter++;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Generics with different type parameters are different types. So `A<int>` and `A<string>` are different classes, and so are allocated different statics.

Answer (score 3):

This is by design. An instance of `A<int>` is not an instance of  `A<string>` they are different classes so there are 2 static variable one for each class.

Answer (score 0):

`A<int>` is actually a different class than `A<string>`, hence they have different static counters

This is why Resharper flags static variables in generics because so few programmers seems to understand statics and especially statics in generics